Customize windows compression
Will compressing smaller files improve read performance on Windows? If so, how can I configure Windows to compress only files up to a specific size limit, such as 10MB? Is there a built-in option for this, or is a script or third-party software required?
Is this code correct?
# Define the directory to process
$directory = "C:\Path\To\Your\Folder"

# Define the size limit (10MB in bytes)
$sizeLimit = 10MB

# Get all files in the directory that are less than or equal to the size limit
Get-ChildItem -Path $directory -File | Where-Object { $_.Length -le $sizeLimit } | ForEach-Object {
    # Compress each file that meets the criteria
    Compress-Archive -Path $_.FullName -DestinationPath "$($_.FullName).zip"
}

